# How do I save background color to localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a to-do list that saves to localStorage with a Priority button that changes the background color to red. That color doesn't save on refresh or adding a new to-do item. Is it possible to save color to localStorage?
https://jsfiddle.net/kiddigit/hg6w01zn/

```
function priority() {
  var id = this.getAttribute('value');
  var todos = get_todos();

  localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));
  document.getElementById(id).style.background = "red";

  return false;
}
```

Comment: So set another item.

Comment: I don't think local storage is the problem here, but we have no idea what is in todos since it's calling a function that isn't shown.

Comment: That get_todos() is in the fiddle. Didn't want to include everything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store a background color with the item, you're going to need to store the item as an object instead of just the name.

I recommend adding logic like this to your add method:

```
function add() {
    var task = document.getElementById('task').value;
    var todos = get_todos();
    var newTask = {
                name:task, 
                id: "item" + todos.length, 
                priority: {
                            isPriority:false, 
                            color:""
                          }
             };

    todos.push(newTask);
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

    show();

    return false;
}
```

Then, when you show() those, your loop will look like this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
      var todo = todos[i];
      html += "<p id='item" + i + "' isPriority='" + 
      todo.priority.isPriority + "'>" + todo["name"] + '<p>' + 
      "<button class='remove'>Delete</button>" + " " + 
      "<button class='priority' value='item" + i + "'>Priority</button>";
  };
```

Then when you set the priority on the object, you're just setting the

```
todos[i].priority.isPriority = true;
```

and

```
todos[i].priority.color = "red";
```

If you want to define your color based on the property, you could just set a property in the html as isPriority=true and then in css do this:

```
[isPriority="true"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Check out this example:  https://jsfiddle.net/1Lgrb7c8/2/

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand about half of it, so I'm going to have to dig in and see if I can figure it all out. It did occur to me that I'd have to store it as an object but I got lost after that.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for doing that. It's going to be awesome to go through this and figure out how you did your magic.

Comment: Cool!  I left the color property in there in case you wanted to come back and later set a different color that is dynamic, but right now it's just using the true/false of isPriority.

Comment: Now I just need to clean up some formatting to make text white and to make it a bit prettier.