# How to keep menu item selected after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this table with parent and children folders. I am trying to make the parent's background highlight yellow when it is selected so that it will be easier to know that it is selected. However for some reason (I did not build this) whenever the menu item is clicked on the page is refreshed so the highlighted background goes away. How can I make the background remain highlighted please even after refresh? Thanks alot.

This is my code:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.rows');

var fnClick = function(){
    var ie = document.querySelectorAll('.rows');
    for (var x = 0; x < ie.length; x++) {
        elems[x].classList.remove("bg-color");
    }
    this.classList.add("bg-color");

}

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
     elems[i].addEventListener("click", fnClick);
}
```

Comment: You have your answer in the tags, using localstorage

Comment: You can use cookies or local storage as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575999/how-do-i-save-background-color-to-localstorage

Answer (score -1):

Well I guess you can store this information into the local storage and check when the page loads if this information is there. Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes I've been trying to use local storage but it is still not working for me !!!

Answer (score -1):

just record what index was selected and after the refresh add the color to the last selected stored index